# UIView : frame size different of bounds size?

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, bounds

Is it possible to have an UIView with its bounds size different of its frame size?

I'm trying to create an UIView with "{{0,0},{320,367}}" frame and "{{0,15},{320,337}}" bounds but i can't get it done using setBounds() and setFrame().

I got from the doc that changing bounds or frame changes frame or bounds accordingly but i thought it was OK to have different values for theses.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically:
1. The bounds is at (0,0) while the frame (and center) give the view's position.
2. The bounds and frame would have the same width and height.

**UPDATE**
It sounds like you want to add a button below a specific view that was previously larger.
In this case, I would create a new view that occupies the full space. Then, I would add the now smaller specific view in the desired position as a subview. Finally, I would add the new button in the desired position as another subview to the new full space view.
You can do this layout in Interface Builder or code.

Comment: I'm trying to resize a view in order to have a blank space beneath it. Since i want to add a button in this blank space, i would like the view to get resized modifying the bounds but with the original frame  size so my button is touchable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i guess i might have issues doing so since my view & controller have delegates and stuff. But i'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, when the device is rotated, your entire view hierarchy is transform'd using a CGAffineTransform. In this case, your bounds and frames may have different values. The best way to assure position of a view is to set its bounds property for the size, and its center property for the position.